# Macbook Pro kernel panic - without something plugged in?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro-retina, kernel-panic

Last year I had the screen replaced on my late '13 MBPr and it has worked fine until recently. At this point I need to have something plugged in for it not to crash - either an external monitor or my usb soundcard. 
If I unplug them it's gonna it's gonna kernel panic within minutes, usually right away: the screen is gonna go black and sometimes the fan starts accelerating to full thrusters where other times it shuts down. Nothing in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`.  If I start the computer with nothing plugged in it's gonna reach the desktop (not necessarily notifying me of a 'restart because of a failure') and within a couple of minutes crash.

The computer is (for this reason) newly wiped and reinstalled to 10.11.4. Would this be a software issue?

Any help on what I should do from here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try reinstalling OS X maybe?

Comment: As mentioned, I recently reinstalled the OS for this reason

Comment: Bummer. What did the apple store say?